# Robot Framework: Is there general setting for the Wait Until Element Is Visible

Tags: robotframework

In the Robot Framework it is good to check that the element is loaded in the page with the

```
Wait Until Element Is Visible
```

keyword before using the element. I have implemented my own keywords:

```
Push
    [Arguments]    ${element}
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    ${element}    10
    Click Element    ${element}

Insert                                                                         
    [Arguments]    ${elementti}    ${text}
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    ${elementti}    10
    Input Text    ${elementti}    ${text}
```

I'm using these keywords like this:

```
Push    elementId
Insert    elementId    text
```

Is there general setting so I don't need my own keywords? There is general variable ${DELAY}, but (according to the documentation) with it all executed commands are delayed and the test takes too much time.

BR,

Sakke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the documentation, you can set an implicit wait.

You can specify this when you load the library (by setting the *implicit_wait* option),  or through the keyword [Set selenium implicit wait](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Set%20Selenium%20Implicit%20Wait)).

However, this won't cause the application to wait for an element to be *visible*. It causes selenium commands to wait until an element is *available* in the DOM.

Comment: This works. I use now: Library  | Selenium2Library | 20 | 20. I have to put timeout and implicit wait to 0 second before the Page Should Not Contain keyword and return values back after the command execution. Otherwise the Page Should Not Contain keyword would take 40 seconds. But I have my own keyword for this. Is there other possibility to handle  the Page Should Not Contain keyword?